# Getting this output while trying to customize the theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "wp_print_media_templates" not found or invalid function name in /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 Stack trace: #0 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2208): do_action('wp_print_footer...') #3 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/block-editor.php(368): wp_print_footer_scripts() #4 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/block-editor.php(613): _wp_get_iframed_editor_assets() #5 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php(850): get_block_editor_settings(Array, Object(WP_Block_Editor_Context)) #6 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Customize_Widgets->enqueue_scripts('') #7 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-admin/customize.php(123): do_action('customize_contr...') #10 {main} thrown in /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 310

getting this error.

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "wp_print_media_templates" not found or invalid function name in /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 Stack trace: #0 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2208): do_action('wp_print_footer...') #3 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/block-editor.php(368): wp_print_footer_scripts() #4 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/block-editor.php(613): _wp_get_iframed_editor_assets() #5 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php(850): get_block_editor_settings(Array, Object(WP_Block_Editor_Context)) #6 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Customize_Widgets->enqueue_scripts('') #7 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-admin/customize.php(123): do_action('customize_contr...') #10 {main} thrown in /home/vatsintech/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 310

How to resolve this error?